# AngularJS, MySQL, PHP, JSON - Data not displayed from Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

HELP! Please. I'm new at using SQL, PHP, and JSON to make databases.

My data is not displaying from database(localhost), using XAMPP.
I create Php line to fetch data from MySQL then create JSON file so AngularJS can handle it. But my data isn't display at all.

In the Dev tools (Chrome) no errors are displayed. Is there anything wrong with the code or the database i created?

[MYSQL pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuNYE.png)

[Columns pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAyRw.png)

[SELECT* PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FzoK.png)

**Here is my api.php**

```
<?php

        $db_name  = 'talents';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

        $sql = 'SELECT id, name, images, images2, images3, indexing FROM talents';

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        $json = json_encode( $result );

        echo $json;
?>
```

**This is my app.js**

```
(function () {

    var alice = angular
        .module('alice', [])
        .controller('AliceController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('api.php').
            then(function (talents) {
                $scope.talents = talents;
            });

        });


})();
```

Last is my HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AliceController" class="talent-container">
    <div ng-repeat="talent in talents" class="card boxed" ng-class=" {{talent.indexing}}">
        <div class="actionlist">
            <div id="id"><span>{{talent.id}}</span></div>
            <div class="addBtn">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/icons/plus.svg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="loveBtn">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/icons/heart-in-a-circle.svg"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media">
            <div><img id="slideShow" ng-src="{{talent.images}}"></div>
            <div class="hide"><img id="slideShow" ng-src="{{talent.images2}}"></div>
            <div class="hide"><img id="slideShow" ng-src="{{talent.images3}}"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div id="name">{{talent.name}}</div>
            <div class="button medium">
                <a href="detail.html" class="moreBtn">MORE</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills-thumb">
            <a ng-repeat="skill in talent.skills" href="#" class="boxedMedium">{{skill.name}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: in Chrome dev tools you can see response from server it helps determine where problem is on server or client

Comment: in your js you have ... $scope.talents = talents; ... and in your HTML your talent variable is singular, it's normal? Do you a ngFor loop around your html code?

Comment: extent your http call to allow error callback: `$http.get('api.php').then((res) => {$scope.talents = res.data;}, (err)=>{console.log(err)});`

Comment: @mickaelw in my HTML i use ng-repeat to call singular from array "talent in talents"

Comment: @AlekseySolovey no error found in console

Answer (score 1):

Definitely implement the error handler on your http service.

First I would use postman to call the api directly and see if you get any response. If not then chances are your issue is on the php side.

If you do get a response and you aren't seeing any call being made in firebug when you load the page with the angular itself then chances are it's on the js/client side.

Chrome won't tell you something an error unless it comes back from the server with an error code, you could just be serving up an empty 200.

Comment: Get this Request Headers from api.php =              
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost/alice/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36

Comment: If you aren't seeing anything in the body when you use POSTman/CURL then the issue is on the php/server side.
Stupid question perhaps but do you actually have any data in your database?

If you're just learning php now would be a good time to check out try/catch and exception handling.

I don't see any glaring issues in your code. So do this.

1. set  php error reporting to ALL ( only in dev ), use try/catch
2. try the query in mysql and make sure it works
3. Use Postman or curl to hit api.
4. Don't even focus on client side before knowing the api works.